# IntelliJ 13.1.6 TestNG Unable to open debugger port : java.net.SocketException "Socket closed"

Tags: java, sockets, debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to run tests locally on IntelliJ 13.1.6, and I can run the tests fine, but the debugger gives me a tiny response:

[image]

I have been trying to solve this for ages, I can't find the debug configurations.

I have googled the crap out of this and most of the things give me tips for android studio or a newer version of IntelliJ. I even tried reinstalling. There are no breakpoints whatsoever, hidden or otherwise. I don't know where to find the socket or why it's closed. Any help appreciated

Comment: It's a very poor message. You don't get 'socket closed' trying to open anything. The socket *was* open and now it is closed while trying to do something else. They should fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

Needed to switch to Java 1.8. I had been using 1.7. Have no idea why this worked or what was going on. This took me weeks to fix. That debugger tool is definitely worth it though...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
- Run --> Edit Configurations --> alt+insert --> new TestNG config --> paste to VM options field:

-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=127.0.0.1:61526

This should work.

Comment: Exact same thing happens :(

Comment: Are you sure that you're running tests with THAT configuration?

Comment: This is the best manual: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-testng.html